# Android Studio - Canary 8: Can't access the resources in feature modules and library modules

Tags: android, android-resources, android-instant-apps

I can't access to the feature module resources and the resources from another library which is included as an API in InstantApp. The only place where it recognises to get resources is the base feature class. I have the following sample: when I run the application there are several Fragment classes in the feature module which have to be loaded along with the layouts also located in that module, but it always fails with

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
```

Tried to exclude Multi-Dexing, other modules, also disabled the aapt2, after which it has started to complain about not found views.

What could be the reason of this?

[A bug is reported here.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64100568)

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64100568), it has been fixed with Android SDK Built-Tools to 27.0.2

Please update your Android SDK Built-Tools to 27.0.2 And ensure you are on Android Studio 3.0.1 or newer.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64100568) they will re-open to examine.